# Can I use a remote folder as GeoServer data directory

Tags: geoserver

Can I define a remote folder as Geoserver [data directory](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/setting.html#datadir-setting)? My Geoserver installation is on Ubuntu and the data directory that I would like to save/fetch my data from is located on a Windows server that exists in the same network.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you have mounted the directory on the server and `tomcat` or which ever user is running GeoServer can read **and write** to the data folder then it will work.

However it will be slow as there will be a network link to traverse for each map.