# Geoserver data directory on a network drive?

Tags: geoserver

is it possible to set the data directory of geoserver on a network drive? The data directory path of my existing installation is the default location (C:\Program Files\GeoServer 2.6.1\data_dir). I copied the folder on a network drive (a mapped drive: I:\GeoServer_Data_Dir (read and write permission for the used Windows-User)) and change the environment variable (GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR) to the new location. After restarting the geoserver service he didn´t use the "new" data dir. Instead he uses C:\Program Files\GeoServer 2.6.1\webapps\geoserver\data as the data directory. In addition i installed GeoServer 2.8.3 on this Computer and during the installing i set the data directory path to the existing folder on the network drive. It said that the path contains a valid data directory but the GeoServer 2.8.3 also uses the webapps\geoserver\data-folder in his home-directory.

Has anybody an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: In Geoserver Data directory (when you have all your workspaces, layers,... the folder you should copy to make backup) is  ..\webapps\geoserver\data not data_dir. You can check this in Geoserver section Server > Server Status > Data directory.

Comment: You should edit /webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml and modify the context param GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, the original data directory path of my geoserver was C:\Program Files\GeoServer 2.6.1\data_dir (default path on windows installer, compare http://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/datadirectory/data-dir-creating.html ). There are stored all my workspaces, layers... . if i change this path in the enviroment variable to the new location on the network drive (or use it as the path for an existing data directory on a new installation) geoserver ignores this path and uses ..\webapps\geoserver\data instead as data directory.

Comment: Do i change this variable back to the default path geoserver use this directory. But i don´t understand why he ignores the network drive path and uses ...\webapps\geoserver\data. I also edit the context param GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR and changed it to the network path but geoserver also ignored it and used ...\webapps\geoserver\data.

Comment: Is there maybe a "special" user for geoserver who have to get read and write permission on the network drive (besides the Windows-User)? (See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188623/can-i-use-a-remote-folder-as-geoserver-data-directory ) But i didn´t installed geoserver on a webserver. I used the windows installer-version.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter the error when you change the data directory, go changed directory and create a new file called "global.xml" then click Browse button in installation window and select the same directory again. Then complete the installation.

Finally, go to default data directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.11.1\data_dir), copy all and paste them to new directory that is  contained "global.xml" and accept the replacement. It should be works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to set the data directory of geoserver on a network drive.

In windows you need to edit the 'startup.bat' file in (`C:\GeoServer_Installation_Folder\bin`).

Change the `-DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR` flag to `-DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="Z:\data_dir"` where Z is the network drive letter.